# Receive json respone instead of x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, json, webhooks, mailgun

I'm trying to config webhooks for my application, everything works fine but when i'm calling post method for opens mail, i'm getting data type of x-www-form-urlencoded but i would like to receive json. How can i do it? Should i change something in my code? or in admin panel on mailgun site?

When i changed in my config to send emails:

```
webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

to:

```
webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

Then i'm unable to receive emails.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't configure the content type of mailgun webhooks -- you'll have to accept the x-www-form-urlencoded format.